# Problem after upgrading to django 5.0 "AttributeError: 'BlankChoiceIterator' object has no attribute '__len__' "

Tags: python, django

I'm new in django triad to upgrade to version 5.0 but got this problem in my project

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 114, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 92, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 159, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
 File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 325, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 325, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 325, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/crispy_forms/templatetags/crispy_forms_field.py", line 125, in render
    return str(field)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 79, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 95, in as_widget
    attrs = self.build_widget_attrs(attrs, widget)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 270, in build_widget_attrs
    widget.use_required_attribute(self.initial)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 781, in use_required_attribute
    first_choice = next(iter(self.choices), None)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_countries/widgets.py", line 29, in get_choices
    self._choices: ChoiceList = list(self._choices)
  File "dirto/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 188, in __wrapper__
    return getattr(result, __method_name)(*args, **kw)
AttributeError: 'BlankChoiceIterator' object has no attribute '__len__'
```

I triad to get help from chatgpt but didn't understand much
it give me this answer

The error you're encountering, AttributeError: 'BlankChoiceIterator' object has no attribute '**len**', is likely related to changes in Django 5.0, specifically to the forms.ChoiceField and its handling of choices.

In Django 5.0, the default behavior for the choices parameter in ChoiceField has changed. It now requires choices to be an iterable of tuples, and the first element of each tuple should be unique.

Comment: Please add your **forms.py** and **views.py** where you are using a form with a `ChoiceField` and lets go from there.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using a package that populates the field you'll get this error. I am going to use `django-countries` as an example. If you're using a similar library, you want to get the actual choices and pass them into `models.CharField` with a choices parameter and call the choices. Let me know if this fixes it. It would be lovely to have you post your model or form

```python
from django_countries.fields import CountryField


# Create your models here.

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    # ... other fields

    country = models.CharField(max_length=200,  null=True, choices=CountryField().choices + [('', 'Select Country')])

    class Meta:
        abstract = True`
```

Comment: Note: you might need to wrapp the `CountryField().choices` in `list(CountryField().choices)`. Otherwise, I got: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Countries' and 'list'`

Comment: thanks!!! Was scratching my head around this issue, precisely with CountryField.

Answer (score 6):

Found this when I ran into the same problem with django-countries, however @Dev Savvi's answer didn't work for me. There's a temporary patch you can put in your `settings.py` which fixes this, until such times as django-countries is updated to work with Django 5.X

```
from django_countries.widgets import LazyChoicesMixin

LazyChoicesMixin.get_choices = lambda self: self._choices
LazyChoicesMixin.choices = property(LazyChoicesMixin.get_choices, LazyChoicesMixin.set_choices)
```

Issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/issues/447).

Comment: This solution also worked successfully for me with a TextChoices field that was not part of the django-countries package.

Comment: This is a better solution. The one from Dev Savvi, works fine too, but needed me to make so many changes in my codebase because I used 'country.name' and 'country.code' in some places